# Split 1 excel sheet to multiple excel sheets (1000 records each)

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have an excel sheet with more than 60k records. I want to split this excel sheet into multiple sheets which have 1000 records each.

Is there a way to implement that in VBScript or directly in excel?

For now I have below code which takes a range of cells and save as another file.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\User\users.xlsx")

objWorkbook.Worksheets("users").Range("A1:A1000").Copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
objWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\user\Desktop\User\Sample57.xlsx", 51
```

In above code can we make modification such that it loops over all the rows and automate for whole excel sheet?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I tried using package UTL_FILE in SQL to read through the file and then create new one.

But, for using this the resource excel file should be on the server.

I don't have much knowledge about VBScript and was suggested that it can be done through VBScript.

I am looking for just a hint on the approach to follow.